# .Net MVC get Lambda expression in Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

In .Net MVC we use Editor Templates to output HTML. So in a View we write something like below and the Editor Template for String (Description is a string object) outputs the correct HTML and controls for the string type:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Entity.Description)
```

I want to create an Editor Template that is able to use\recreate the Lambda expression that I used in the view i.e. model.Entity.Description. In the Editor Template I can retrieve the property name in this case Description however I'd like to be able to retrieve the Lambda expression in the Editor Template that I used in the View i.e. model => model.Entity.Description
An example Editor Template is below - I want to replace MYLAMBDAEXPRESSIONHERE with the relevant expression dynamically i.e. model => model.Entity.Description:

```
@model IDictionary Fields //Or some object that also contains the lambda expression 
@using System.Collections;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using Mallon.Core.Artifacts;

@{
   var fieldName = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
   FieldAccessOptionality access = (FieldAccessOptionality)Model[fieldName];

   switch(access)
   {
      case FieldAccessOptionality.None:
         break;
      case FieldAccessOptionality.Mandatory:
         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(MYLAMBDAEXPRESSIONHERE)
         </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(MYLAMBDAEXPRESSIONHERE)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(MYLAMBDAEXPRESSIONHERE)
         </div>
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean, displaying a property which name is only known at runtime ?

Comment: I want to display the 'model => model.Entity.Description' property in the editor. I'm looking at HTML Helpers which may offer me a solution to pass the Lambda expression as a parameter.

Comment: It's still not clear what problem have you faced, i.e. why cannot you simply write lambda where you want it to be?

Comment: I've edited the original post with some additional details for clarity. Basically I want to access the lambda expression I used in the View in the Editor Template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the lambda expression in the template but you can use the ModelMetadata in order to obtain further information. For example,

```
 @ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName
```

gives you the property name. In your example, "Description".